# highcharts-chart error series undefined, pero se ve el grafico

Tags: angular, highcharts

Estoy realizando un proyecto en angular (7) y al poner las gráficas de highchart (módulo highcharts-chart), me arroja el siguiente error por consola:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined
```

Lo raro es que el gráfico se muestra bien, pero creo que o le estoy pasando mal las variables, o mal inicializado o algo así, por lo tanto, aunque se me vea, me gustaría dejarlo sin errores de consola.

El codigo que tengo que es el siguiente.

**Template HTML**

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="graficoOptions"></highcharts-chart>
```

**Controlador**

```
this._contratosService.getEstados(localStorage.getItem('idCliente')).subscribe(
        async data => {
          this.graficoOptions= this._funcionesService.decodificarToken(data);
          for (let i = 0; i < this.arraySituaciones.length; i++) {
            this.array = this.array.concat([
              {
                name: this.arraySituaciones[i],
                y: this.arrayContadorContratos[i],
                selected: false
              }
            ]);
          }

          this.options = JSON.parse(this._GraficosService.graficosOption);
          this.graficoOptions= {
            lang: this.options,
            chart: { type: 'line' },
            exporting: {
              buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                  menuItems: [
                    'printChart',
                    'separator',
                    'downloadPNG',
                    'downloadJPEG',
                    'downloadPDF',
                    'downloadSVG',
                    'separator',
                    'downloadCSV',
                    'downloadXLS'
                  ]
                }
              }

            },
            title: { text: 'Estados de los contratos' },
            subtitle: {
              text:
                'Se muestran la cantidad de contratos que existen en cada estado.'
            },
            tooltip: {
              pointFormat:
                '<span style="color:{series.color}">Contratos: </span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
              shared: true
            },
            series: [
              {
                type: 'pie',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                keys: ['name', 'y', 'selected', 'sliced'],
                data: this.array,
                showInLegend: true
              }
            ],
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                  click: function(e) {
                    console.log('1234');
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            credits: { enabled: false }
          };
        });
```

Comment: Necesitaría ver todo el componente para hacerme una idea de dónde puede estar el fallo. Puede ser que `this.graficoOptions` sea undefined hasta que responda tu llamada

Comment: Hola, esta inicializado así graficoOptions: any;, tienes razón, ¿puede que vayan por ahí los tiros no?

Comment: que tal si haces algo como `<highcharts-chart *ngIf="graficoOptions"[Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="graficoOptions"></highcharts-chart>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se presenta porque estas declarando el grafico al inicio del template, al ingresar al componente las series están indefinidas porque no le llega ningún valor, pero luego cuando lo declaras en el método lo vuelve a reconstruir por eso se visualiza el gráfico

Debes definir el valor por defecto de `graficoOptions` quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
  graficoOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [],
        type: 'column'
      }
    ]
  };
```

> Añado un ejemplo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmvg1f) donde pueden ver la solución del error

Comment: puedes mejorar tu respuesta, que harias para evitar el error; si bien la respuesta puede ayudar muchos pueden considerar que tu respuesta es de baja calidad

Comment: Como explica @JackNavaRow, sería genial que pongas un ejemplo verificable, o algo que respalde tu respuesta.

Comment: Claro, ahí añadí una posible solución al error

Comment: @JhonnyPerez edite un poco la respuesta para que sea acorde al sitio, para la proxima te invito a hacerlo tu, considero que fue una buena respuesta

Comment: Gracias @JhonnyPerez pero ya no puedo testearlo, paso mucho tiempo desde la pregunta.